# typo3 Template Auto-parser plugin not visible

Tags: templates, typo3

I'm following the *Modern Template Building* [tutorial](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/tutorials/doc_tut_templselect/0.1.0/view/1/3/#id1861460) and fail to install the *Template Auto-parser* extension.

After the installation it should show the plugin in the object browser:
[image]

Unfortunately the `tx_automaketemplate_pi1` part is never showing up.

Needless to say that all atempts to use the extension do not work.

Any ideas about how to fix that?

I'm on a fresh installation of Typo3 4.7.0.

**Update:**

After installing typo3 4.5 and trying again I noticed, that an extension is downloaded only and has to be installed in an extra step. However the icons which are indicating this (the brick with + or -) are not visible on my 4.7.0 installation:

[image]

Since the icons are not there I did not find a way to really install the extension. On the 4.5.0 installation everything is working fine.

Just out of curiousity. Any ideas about how to get the brik icons?

Comment: Weird, i just installed the ext on 4.5+ to check without any problems. But other suggestion keep in mind that _Modern Template Building_ is not so modern, as it was when the documentation was written (8 years ago!). If I had to choose now I would definitely go for TemplaVoila, it does much more things not only in `frontend` but also in `backend`. It allows ie. for placing headers, contents images etc. without additional TypoScript required. Also you can simulate ie. simple plugins without writing custom extensions etc. Just consider. And read its documentation, not _Futuristic_ tutorial

Comment: A little bit of topic, but can you provide a link of "And read its documentation, not Futuristic tutorial"?

Comment: Most of TYPO3 extensions has a documentation in its folder, always in `doc/manual.sxw` file. You can also read it online or download from: http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/templavoila/current/

Comment: I suggest to use `gridelements` to together with the buildin fluid templates instead. If you want to have something powerful, try `fed` with `fluidcontent` http://extensions.fedext.net/fluid-content/overview.html

Comment: Oh and btw, just because `modern template building` is old, does not mean it is outdated. If you understood the concept, you will still find everything where it used to be. There were only little changes ind colors and moving fields around in the form. I hope you have read the getting started tutorial!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a firefox specific problem (see http://www.xwissen.info/web-log/detail/articel/fix-install-uninstall-in-typo3-extansion-manager.html). I tried the workaround from xwissen.info (add "position: absolute" to .t3-icon-system-extension-uninstall and .t3-icon-system-extension-install) and this solved the issue.

Comment: Correct, this happens with all non webkit browsers. The next round of updates will take care about this.